# Mezzanine Cartridge rating form customization?

Tags: html, css, django, mezzanine, cartridge

Hello i'm trying to customize product page in Mezzanine Cartridge shop.
I have a problem with the rating form customization.

Now it looks like this [rating form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnP6n.jpg)
To get this look, I used some CSS code

```
/* Ratings */
.rating {margin:15px; text-align: center;}
.rating * {display:inline !important; list-style-type:none;}
.rating label {margin-right:15px;}
.rating p {margin-right:20px;}
.rating ul {margin-left:0 !important; padding:0 !important;}
.rating li {border:none !important; background:none !important; padding:0 !important;display: inline-block;}
.rating li input {margin-top:-4px;}
#comments .rating {padding:0 !important; margin:10px 0 0 0 !important;
               border:none !important; background:none !important;}
```

My goal is to make simple rating form with stars instead of number.
Can any body help?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image.

Comment: Did you find out?

Comment: no. I have code liket this. https://codepen.io/gowa66/pen/rjdLXy . 
But part of html is rendering by cms.